# Is having a different domain per state in Brazil a good SEO strategy?

Tags: seo, local-seo

Being short: Having one domain per state (country's states. Brazil in this case) on the same ccTLD and redirecting users to the localized website, all of them possibly but not necessarily linking back to the parent site, is good for SEO? Or can this impact negatively?

The website already has different content for each state, it's just a possible course of action to get other states to rank better, since most search is done for specific states. We have a lot of reach on a couple states, but we want to get other states to rank better, and having them on the domain and website name looked like a really good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do redirects unless you absolutely have to (like actually centralizing or breaking content). There's no gain and quite a few risks. You should just decide whether you want to have separate sites (only advisable if you already have some with very good standing and don't want to give them up) or having a single one with localised sections (good in most other cases - it's easier to manage, more helpful for your readers, has more convincing density of content etc).

Comment: Its better to keep the contents in the primary domain for example, company.com/br-en/ and give the Brazil specific content in a language English. And redirect the country specific domain to it. The main site, when having good content, will come up in SEO due to legitimate content and domain authority.